# Вывод из Json массива всех ключей с определенным значением

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Я создаю структуру в `html` вида:

```
<span data-jsonItem="key__s" data-jsonValue="acdtime" data-segment="100"></span>
<span data-jsonItem="key__s" data-jsonValue="acdtime" data-segment="54"></span>
```

С помощью `jsonItem` я получаю `ключ` с массивом и нахожу значение по `jsonValue`.

Код `JS`:

```
function jsonUPDATE() {
var URL = ""
  $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
    $('span').html(function() {
      var $span = $(this);
      var $spandata = data[$span.data('jsonitem')][0][$span.data('jsonvalue')];         
      return $spandata;
    });
  });
}
```

В `URL` находится `json` ниже. Появилась необходимость выводить данные по фильтру. Для этого добавил `data-segment`. В нем будет указываться значение и на основании этого значения в `span` нужно будет фильтровать весь массив. Есть идеи по апгрейду скрипта?

Сам `json`:

```
{
  "key__s": [
      {
          "id": 12345621, 
          "row_date": 123456, 
          "segment_id": 1, 
          "ringtime": 0.0, 
          "acdtime": 32.0, 
          "holdtime": 0.0, 
          "acwtime": 0.0, 
          "segment_id": 100, 
      },
      {
          "id": 12345624, 
          "row_date": 123456, 
          "segment_id": 1, 
          "ringtime": 0.0, 
          "acdtime": 32.0, 
          "holdtime": 0.0, 
          "acwtime": 0.0, 
          "segment_id": 54, 
      },
      {
          "id": 123456276, 
          "row_date": 123456, 
          "segment_id": 1, 
          "ringtime": 0.0, 
          "acdtime": 32.0, 
          "holdtime": 0.0, 
          "acwtime": 0.0, 
          "segment_id": 100, 
      }        
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
      {
          "id": 12345621, 
          "row_date": 123456, 
          "segment_id": 1, 
          "ringtime": 0.0, 
          "acdtime": 32.0, 
          "holdtime": 0.0, 
          "acwtime": 0.0, 
          "segment_id": 100 
      },
      {
          "id": 12345624, 
          "row_date": 123456, 
          "segment_id": 1, 
          "ringtime": 0.0, 
          "acdtime": 32.0, 
          "holdtime": 0.0, 
          "acwtime": 0.0, 
          "segment_id": 54 
      },
      {
          "id": 123456276, 
          "row_date": 123456, 
          "segment_id": 1, 
          "ringtime": 0.0, 
          "acdtime": 32.0, 
          "holdtime": 0.0, 
          "acwtime": 0.0, 
          "segment_id": 100
      }        
  ];

var id = 54;
var f = data.filter(function(v) {
    console.log(v.segment_id);
    return v.segment_id === id;
});
console.log(f);
```